# Android 4.4 kitkat CardView Dropdown with ConstraintLayout dont work with the TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition but works on Android 5+

Tags: java, android, xml, android-cardview, card

The problem I'm really sure its the transitionManager, I need an equivalent for old versions. Any advice for doing anything like this would be nice because maybe there are many fields for a card, because I need about 3 more  in a CardView.

Drawables that it need to work:
Name:ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
         android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#8A000000"
        android:pathData="M7.41,7.84L12,12.42l4.59,-4.58L18,9.25l-6,6 -6,-6z"/>
</vector>
```

Name:ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24.0"
            android:viewportHeight="24.0">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#8A000000"
            android:pathData="M7.41,15.41L12,10.83l4.59,4.58L18,14l-6,-6- 
     6,6z"/>
      </vector>
```

**JAVA**

```
package ru.embersoft.expandablecardview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.AutoTransition;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout expandableViewDestinatario;
    ConstraintLayout expandableViewRemitente;
    ConstraintLayout expandableViewTransportista;
    ConstraintLayout expandableViewTitular;
    Button flechaDestinatario,flechaRemitente,flechaTitular,flechaTranspostista;
    CardView cardViewDest,cardViewRem,cardViewTit,cardViewTran;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        expandableViewDestinatario = findViewById(R.id.expandableDestinatario);
        flechaDestinatario = findViewById(R.id.flechaDestinatario);
        cardViewDest = findViewById(R.id.cardViewDestinatario);

        flechaDestinatario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (expandableViewDestinatario.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardViewDest, new AutoTransition());
                    expandableViewDestinatario.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    flechaDestinatario.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp);
                } else {
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardViewDest, new AutoTransition());
                    expandableViewDestinatario.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    flechaDestinatario.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp);
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E4E3E3"
        tools:context=".ui.cargadetallada.DatosPersonasInvolucradasActaAcitivity">
          <!--destinatario-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardViewDestinatario"
            style="@style/CardView.Light"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDatosDestinatario"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Datos Destinatario"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/flechaDestinatario"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvDatosDestinatario"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expandableDestinatario"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDatosDestinatario">
    
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etDomicilioComercial"
                        android:layout_width="351dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="start|top"
                        android:hint="Domicilio Comercial"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etDomicilioDescargaDest"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etRazonSocial" />
    
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etDomicilioDescargaDest"
                        android:layout_width="351dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="start|top"
                        android:hint="@string/domicilio_descarga"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etDomicilioComercial" />
    
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etCuitDestinatario"
                        android:layout_width="351dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Ingrese Cuit"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etRazonSocial"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etRazonSocial"
                        android:layout_width="351dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="start|top"
                        android:hint="Razón Social"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etDomicilioComercial"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etCuitDestinatario" />
    
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**build.grandle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.utearmsa.transito"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
       // testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      //  multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'


   implementation 'com.github.arcadefire:nice-spinner:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.mabbas007:TagsEditText:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.jrummyapps:colorpicker:2.1.6'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //agregada la implementacion para que vuelva a funcionar httpLegacy
   implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

    //Cardviews
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
 

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation files('usdk_api_aidl_limited_v2.0.1.20210608.jar')
    implementation files('usdk_api_aidl_v13.3.1RA.20210902.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    implementation files('ZSDK_API.jar')
    implementation files('libs/acssmc-1.1.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/core-3.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sdtapi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/SmartCardLib.jar')
    implementation files('libs/telpo_api.jar')
    implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }

}
```

[Working as expected on version Android 5+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIfpd.png)

[how is it after pressing the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9SyN.png)

Error that somehow disappear between restarts of the activity
Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener

Comment: Change filter *no filter in your logcat then try you can see logs.. after crashed and relaunch however you can see your logs... And no need min 19 you can increase above or min 21..

Comment: Do you have latest version of Android loaded?

Comment: @GobuCSG, @jdweng The project where I currently working needs support for minSDK 19 because it use a custom android for a posnet and  I have Android Chipmunk 2021.2.1 patch 1.For now i could say that I fixed suppresing the line `                   TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardViewDest, new AutoTransition());`